# How do I make Snow Leopard boot into 64-bit by default?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, 64-bit

I like working in 64-bit now on my iMac and the whole system seems to run a bit faster. The problem is holding down the 6 and 4 during every boot. Is there a way to force this into 64-bit all of the time?

I have searched Google some, but most of the options seems like a hack. Which works and which is easiest to back out of if necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way is to edit the `com.apple.Boot` plist, as [documented on this page](http://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-64bit.html).  The file is located at `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot.plist`.  Find the Kernel Flags key and add `arch=x86_64`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Kernel</key>
    <string>mach_kernel</string>
    <key>Kernel Flags</key>
    <string>arch=x86_64</string>
</dict>
```